# Exponential of Nilpotent Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a nilpotent matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$, let

$exp(A) = Id + \frac{A}{1!} + \frac{A^2}{2!} + \ldots \in M_n(\mathbb R) $.

If $A$ is a nilpotent matrix such that $exp(A) = Id$, then $A$ is zero matrix. (True or False)?

(Id means identity matrix).

At first, i thought that for the right-hand side expression to be equal to $Id$, we must have all the other terms be zero. But then i am not making use of the fact that $A$ is a nilpotent matrix.

So i usually face difficulty with such problems. I can not seem to figure out how to think about this kind of problems.

Comment: This follows by looking at the Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume $A$ is nilpotent,if $A$ is zero we are done, if not  there's least positive integer $k\geq 2$ such that :$A^{k}=0$,if in addition $exp(A) =I$, then $I =I+A+\cdots +A^{k-1}$, So
$A(I+\cdots +A^{k-2})=0$ but this implies $A=0$,because (I+\cdots +A^{k-2})is invertible, this follows from the following facts:

1. if $N$ is nilpotent, then $I+N$ is invertible
   2)if $N, M$ are nilpotent and commute, then $(N+M) $ is nilpotent.